# plot one set of columns against another set using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr, tidyverse

Can `ggplot2` be used to create a plot matrix of one set of columns against another set?

For example, with the dataframe below plot all columns beginning with 'x' against all columns beginning with 'y', to produce a grid of plots.

```
require("tidyverse")

df <- tibble(
  x1 = sample(10),
  x2 = sample(10),
  x3 = sample(10),
  y1 = sample(10),
  y2 = sample(10)
)
```

And what if, unlike in the example above, the columns are not named in a regular pattern - is there a way that arbitrary sets of columns can be chosen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the `expand.grid` function. It should create all 2-way combinations of an arbitrary set of 2 list names. (It's not a part of tidyverse.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape with `tidyr::gather` then facet:

```
df_long <- df %>% 
  gather(x_axis, x, contains("x")) %>% 
  gather(y_axis, y, contains("y"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 60 x 4
>    x_axis     x y_axis     y
>     <chr> <int>  <chr> <int>
>  1     x1    10     y1     6
>  2     x1     6     y1    10
>  3     x1     5     y1     3
>  4     x1     7     y1     8
>  5     x1     8     y1     2
>  6     x1     1     y1     1
>  7     x1     3     y1     5
>  8     x1     9     y1     9
>  9     x1     4     y1     7
> 10     x1     2     y1     4
> # ... with 50 more rows
> ```

Instead of `contains` you can use any other `tidyverse` selection function, or just supply the raw column names.

Then plot:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(y_axis ~ x_axis, switch = "both") +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    theme(strip.placement = "outside", strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

If you need free scales, you can wrap instead:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~ interaction(y_axis, x_axis), scales = "free")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is probably to just loop over all possible combinations, make the respective plot, and then combine all into a grid.

```
require("tidyverse")

df <- tibble(
  x1 = sample(10),
  x2 = sample(10),
  x3 = sample(10),
  y1 = sample(10),
  y2 = sample(10)
)


group1 <- c("x1", "x2", "x3") # set of variables along x axis
group2 <- c("y1", "y2") # set of variables along y axis

plotlist <- list()
for (x in group1) {
  for (y in group2) {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x, y)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste0(y, " versus ", x))
    plotlist <- append(plotlist, list(p))
  }
}

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plotlist)
```

[image]

The last step here uses the cowplot package, which I wrote. Alternatively, you could use `ggarrange` from the egg package to place the plots into a grid.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's a solution that uses `ggduo` from the `GGally` package (a function I just became aware of)

```
require(GGally)    
df %>% ggduo(columnsX = 1:3, columnsY = 4:5)
```